# Custom Trigger when code found inside the page GTM

Tags: wordpress, customization, google-tag-manager

i ask you support to solve my issue. I made a custom code to dinamically fire schema.org snippet data on my site.

I need to trigger this only for blog post. My blog post is identified by this code:

div class="span12" data-motopress-wrapper-file="single.php" data-motopress-wrapper-type="content">

so when i find single.php i have to trigger the right tag into Google Tag Manager.

I need to create a custom dom variable, but i can't reach to understand how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create a **DOM Element** variable with the following configuration:

- `Selection Method`: CSS selector
- `Element Selector`: [data-motopress-wrapper-file]
- `Attribute Name`: data-motopress-wrapper-file

And that variable should return `single.php` which you can then use a trigger (eg if `{{My Dom Element}}` equals `single.php`)

Alternatively, you can create a **Custom JavaScript** variable:

```
function() {
  var attr = "data-motopress-wrapper-file";
  return (document.querySelectorAll('['+attr+']')[0]).attributes[attr].value;
}
```

If you have multiple `data-motopress-wrapper-file` elements on your page, then you can create a function that will search for the specific single.php and return `true/false` based on its presence:

```
function() {
  return (document.querySelectorAll('[data-motopress-wrapper-file="single.php"]').length>0);
}
```